# Magento Admin Panel -

Tags: image, magento

Using Magento Community edition using the Magento Admin Panel.

In Catalog – Manage Products – Images tab the orange “Browse Files” and “Upload Files” buttons have mysteriously moved to the left side of the screen (they were located on the right). I am able to select “Browse Files” and even “Upload Files”. It seems to work at first but after the upload states “complete” the image never populates above.  I can no longer select any radio buttons either for Base Image, Small Image, or Thumbnail.

Everyone in the office has the same issue. Our developers cannot replicate the issue on their end nor can anyone outside of the office. It seems to just be happening in our office. It just started about 1 week ago.

Things I have tried:

- using different browsers
- uninstalling / reinstalling Adobe Flash (making sure latest edition
  installed)
- disabling / reenabling Flash  player in Chrome plugin (and selected
  "always allowed to run"
- uninstalling / reinstalling Chrome browser

Unfortunately, I am not a developer or programmer so I cannot include any code.

Here are a few links of screenshots. I hope that I have included all relevant information and that someone can solve this bizarre mystery. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Compare the HTML & CSS files to find the difference. (Have your devs use diff).